# Array type expected; found 'java.util.Collection<...>'

Tags: java

I have problem when I try to get Bukkit.OnlinePlayers, i don't know from what is coming so i'll be very glad if someone helps me. The problem is in this line `final Player player2 = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[new Random().nextInt(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size())];` Here is the code :

```
@EventHandler
public void onRecord(final PlayerInteractEvent playerInteractEvent) {
    final Player player = playerInteractEvent.getPlayer();
    if (LionStaff.mod.contains(player.getName()) && player.getItemInHand().getType() == Material.RECORD_3 && playerInteractEvent.getAction().toString().contains("RIGHT")) {
        final Player player2 = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()[new Random().nextInt(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size())];
        if (Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() == 1) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "There are not enough players to use this.");
        }
        if (Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().size() > 1) {
            if (player != player2) {
                player.teleport((Entity)player2);
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "You were teleported randomly to " + ChatColor.GOLD + player2.getName() + ChatColor.YELLOW + ".");
            }
            if (player == player2) {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Oops, it just randomly picked up you, please try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `getOnlinePlayers` does not return an array, so you cannot access elements with square brackets. If it's a list, you can use `getOnlinePlayers.get(idx)` ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-)). If it's not a list (as the error seems to suggest), you can make a new list with the result: `new ArrayList<>(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()).get(...)`

Comment: Please mark my response as an answer if helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()
```

Returns Collection<? extends Player>: https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/Bukkit.html#getOnlinePlayers()

You can then do any action you want with the Collection.

Comment: " for (Player player2 : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) { " like this one